# Join query in Cassandra

Tags: join, cassandra

I am new in Cassandra. Although I can do some stuff in SQL, I am finding it pretty hard to do simple join in Cassandra. My schema looks like this:[image]

Now I have to find, **for each department how many emails in total were sent out from employees working there. The output per department shall contain the corresponding number of emails.**

Maybe I am missing some simple thing, but no matter what I do, I am not even being able to retrieve data from two tables.

Comment: As NiVeR said, there is **no** JOIN operation with Cassandra.  If you want, why don't you edit your question to include the JOIN query you were trying to run, and perhaps I can explain how to build a data model to support it.

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra has no `join` operation. It has been implemented in such way to increase the performance in basic operations like reading and writing, but with the caveat that you write to and read from a `single` table at a particular moment.

If your model is relational, so it is based on relations between tables, than Cassandra is not the way to go. In this case you should go with some RDBMS(Relational Database Management System) like: PostgreSQL, MySql, Sql Server etc.